# Setting up a definite spawn point for FirstPersonController in Ursina

Tags: python, ursina

I have two questions.

- I want to set my `FirstPersonController()` to spawn at a definite coordinate. How can I do that ?
- When I run a Ursina code with `FirstPersonController()`, it seems to be locked in a position or falling into void, but I had set up a floor of cube. How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FirstPersonController` can be given a position:

```py
player = FirstPersonController(position=(10, 0, 10))
```

This is also documented in the [ursina cheat sheet](https://www.ursinaengine.org/cheat_sheet_dark.html#FirstPersonController).

If you can't move around you may be stuck inside a block. Try using `space` to jump out. In case you're falling through the ground you may have forgotten to set a collider on it. Please show your relevant code.